# How to combine RegEx conditions?

Tags: regex, qt, regex-group, qregexp, qregularexpression

I need to make a `QLineEdit` with a `QRegularExpressionValidator` with the following 3 constraints:

1. Cannot start with empty space `^[\\S]`
2. Cannot start with Hello `^(?!Hello).+`
3. Cannot end with empty space `^.*[\\S]$`

How do I combine those 3 in one regex so that I can set it a `QRegularExpressionValidator`?

Thank you!

Note: As long as I have a regex that is verifiable with a regex tool I am good. I have specified `Qt` just to provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?!Hello\b)\S(?:.*\S)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!Hello\b)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to thte right is not Hello
- `\S` Match a non whitespace char
- `(?:.*\S)?` Optionally match 0+ times any char except a newline and a non whitespace char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/POgx8o/1)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
var strings = [
  'a',
  'this is ok',
  ' leading space',
  'trailing space ',
  'Hello text',
  'Hello'
];
var re = /^([^\s]|(?!(Hello|\s)).*[^\s])$/;
strings.forEach((str) => {
  var val = re.test(str);
  console.log('"' + str + '" ==> ' + val);
});
```

Console output:

```
"a" ==> true
"this is ok" ==> true
" leading space" ==> false
"trailing space " ==> false
"Hello text" ==> false
"Hello" ==> false
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `^...$` -- anchor at the beginning and end
- `([^\s]|...)` -- logical **or**, where the first part is a single non space char
- `(?!(...)).+` -- negative lookahead
- `(Hello|\s)` -- ... of 'Hello' or space
- `.+[^\s]` -- followed by any number of chars, except space at the end

Comment: It's working except that it expects at least two characters at the start of the string. Could you please fix that? So for instance if I just type "a" it should match, but I get no match.

Comment: ```^(?!(RBX|\\s)).+$``` this seems to solve it, but then the last requirement of not ending with an empty space does not meet.

Comment: Updated the regex with example to allow a single non-space char. Please accept if this solves your question.

Comment: Just typed "Hello" at https://regex101.com and it accepted, which it shouldn't. The single non-space character at the beginning is OK.

Comment: Did you try to tweak the regex? Please, at last show us that you make an effort, not just ask.

Comment: In any case, I updated the answer with a `'Hello'` test case.

Comment: `Hello` should not be legal, with your regex it shows as if its legal. And I did try to tweak it, but with no success. Please look at the answer above. That one works. I have however voted up on your answer since it also gives valuable information.

Comment: Fair enough. Run the code snippet, or test with regex101.com, and you can see that just `Hello` is a no match

Comment: After your last edit yes, it does satisfy all the requirements, which is why I have voted up your answer anyways. But since "The fourth bird's" answer was correct from the very beginning, I chose his as the solution. I think it's only fair, don't you agee?